# Platformio compile error: ArduinoJson6100_100::DynamicJsonDocument has no member named 'nestingLimit'

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, platformio

I'm new to c++, and trying to compile simple arduino project in the Platformio.

platformio.ini file:

```
    [platformio]
src_dir = .
lib_extra_dirs = .piolibdeps/, ../../

[env:nodemcuv2]
platform = espressif8266
board = nodemcuv2
framework = arduino
lib_deps = 
#    PubSubClient
    painlessMesh
```

main.ino file:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <painlessMesh.h>
void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Should be something simple, but I'm getting next error:

> 'ArduinoJson6100_100::DynamicJsonDocument' has no member named
>   'nestingLimit'

Full compiler stack:

> > Executing task in folder test4: platformio run <
>
> Processing nodemcuv2 (platform: espressif8266; board: nodemcuv2;
>   framework: arduino)
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option CONFIGURATION:
>   https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif8266/nodemcuv2.html
>   PLATFORM: Espressif 8266 > NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) HARDWARE:
>   ESP8266 80MHz 80KB RAM (4MB Flash) Converting main.ino Library
>   Dependency Finder ->  LDF MODES:
>   FINDER(chain) COMPATIBILITY(soft) Collected 35 compatible libraries
>   Scanning dependencies... Dependency Graph |--  1.3.0 |
>   |--  6.10.0 |   |--  3.0.2 |   |--
>    1.2.0 |   |   |--  1.0 |   |--
>    1.0 Compiling .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/src/main.ino.cpp.o
>   Generating LD script
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/ld/local.eagle.app.v6.common.ld Archiving
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/libef5/libArduinoJson_ID64.a Archiving
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/libca3/libTaskScheduler_ID721.a Indexing
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/libef5/libArduinoJson_ID64.a Indexing
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/libca3/libTaskScheduler_ID721.a Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/BearSSLHelpers.cpp.o Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/CertStoreBearSSL.cpp.o Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/ESP8266WiFi.cpp.o Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/ESP8266WiFiAP.cpp.o Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/ESP8266WiFiGeneric.cpp.o
>   Compiling .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/ESP8266WiFiMulti.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/ESP8266WiFiSTA-WPS.cpp.o
>   Compiling .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp.o
>   Compiling .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/ESP8266WiFiScan.cpp.o
>   Compiling .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/WiFiClientSecureAxTLS.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp.o
>   Compiling .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/WiFiServerSecureAxTLS.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/WiFiServerSecureBearSSL.cpp.o
>   Compiling .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/ESP8266WiFi/WiFiUdp.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib129/ESPAsyncTCP_ID305/AsyncPrinter.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib129/ESPAsyncTCP_ID305/ESPAsyncTCP.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib129/ESPAsyncTCP_ID305/ESPAsyncTCPbuffer.cpp.o
>   Archiving .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/libESP8266WiFi.a Indexing
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib6c2/libESP8266WiFi.a Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib129/ESPAsyncTCP_ID305/SyncClient.cpp.o Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib129/ESPAsyncTCP_ID305/tcp_axtls.c.o Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/TaskScheduler.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMesh.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMeshAP.cpp.o
>   Archiving .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib129/libESPAsyncTCP_ID305.a Indexing
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib129/libESPAsyncTCP_ID305.a Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMeshComm.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMeshConnection.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMeshDebug.cpp.o
>   Compiling
>   .pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMeshJson.cpp.o
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshComm.cpp: In member
>   function 'String painlessMesh::buildMeshPackage(uint32_t, uint32_t,
>   meshPackageType, String&)':
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshComm.cpp:68:25: error:
>   no matching function for call to
>   'ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument()'
>   DynamicJsonDocument jsonBuffer; ^
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshComm.cpp:68:25: note:
>   candidates are: In file included from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/DynamicJsonDocument.hpp:7:0,
>   from .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.hpp:21, from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.h:9, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMesh.h:12, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshComm.cpp:8:
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:50:3:
>   note:
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(ArduinoJson6100_100::VariantRef)
>   [with TAllocator = ArduinoJson6100_100::DefaultAllocator]
>   BasicJsonDocument(VariantRef src) ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:50:3:
>   note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:43:3:
>   note: template
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(const
>   T&, typename
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::enable_if::value>::type*)
>   BasicJsonDocument(const T& src, ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:43:3:
>   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshComm.cpp:68:25: note: 
>   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided DynamicJsonDocument
>   jsonBuffer; ^ In file included from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/DynamicJsonDocument.hpp:7:0,
>   from .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.hpp:21, from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.h:9, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMesh.h:12, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshComm.cpp:8:
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:36:3:
>   note:
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(const
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument&) [with TAllocator
>   = ArduinoJson6100_100::DefaultAllocator] BasicJsonDocument(const BasicJsonDocument& src) ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:36:3:
>   note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:33:12:
>   note:
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(size_t,
>   TAllocator) [with TAllocator = ArduinoJson6100_100::DefaultAllocator;
>   size_t = unsigned int] explicit BasicJsonDocument(size_t capa,
>   TAllocator allocator = TAllocator()) ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:33:12:
>   note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshConnection.cpp: In
>   member function 'void MeshConnection::handleMessage(String&,
>   uint32_t)':
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshConnection.cpp:543:25:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   'ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument()'
>   DynamicJsonDocument jsonBuffer; ^
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshConnection.cpp:543:25:
>   note: candidates are: In file included from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/DynamicJsonDocument.hpp:7:0,
>   from .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.hpp:21, from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.h:9, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMesh.h:12, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshConnection.cpp:9:
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:50:3:
>   note:
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(ArduinoJson6100_100::VariantRef)
>   [with TAllocator = ArduinoJson6100_100::DefaultAllocator]
>   BasicJsonDocument(VariantRef src) ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:50:3:
>   note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:43:3:
>   note: template
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(const
>   T&, typename
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::enable_if::value>::type*)
>   BasicJsonDocument(const T& src, ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:43:3:
>   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshConnection.cpp:543:25:
>   note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided DynamicJsonDocument
>   jsonBuffer; ^ In file included from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/DynamicJsonDocument.hpp:7:0,
>   from .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.hpp:21, from
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson.h:9, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMesh.h:12, from
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshConnection.cpp:9:
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:36:3:
>   note:
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(const
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument&) [with TAllocator
>   = ArduinoJson6100_100::DefaultAllocator] BasicJsonDocument(const BasicJsonDocument& src) ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:36:3:
>   note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:33:12:
>   note:
>   ArduinoJson6100_100::BasicJsonDocument::BasicJsonDocument(size_t,
>   TAllocator) [with TAllocator = ArduinoJson6100_100::DefaultAllocator;
>   size_t = unsigned int] explicit BasicJsonDocument(size_t capa,
>   TAllocator allocator = TAllocator()) ^
>   .piolibdeps/ArduinoJson_ID64/src/ArduinoJson/Document/BasicJsonDocument.hpp:33:12:
>   note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
>   .piolibdeps/painlessMesh_ID1269/src/painlessMeshConnection.cpp:544:16:
>   error: 'ArduinoJson6100_100::DynamicJsonDocument' has no member named
>   'nestingLimit' jsonBuffer.nestingLimit = 255; ^
>   *** [.pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMeshComm.cpp.o]
>   Error 1
>   *** [.pioenvs/nodemcuv2/lib3f1/painlessMesh_ID1269/painlessMeshConnection.cpp.o]
>   Error 1
>   ======================================== [ERROR] Took 10.54 seconds ======================================== The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the library source: https://gitlab.com/painlessMesh/painlessMesh/issues/253

Author comment:

> Thanks for reporting. This should be fixed in the latest version
>   (1.3.1). Let me know if you still have problems